# git pull and bogus local changes

Tags: git

I see this has been asked many times already, usually with different caveats. In my case, I'm using git to deploy changes from my local dev box, up to a git server, and finally, to pull changes onto a web server via cron job.

My workflow is this:

1. Commit changes to local working copy
2. Push changes to upstream server (created as a bare repo, which I pushed my local to)
3. `git pull -Xingore-space-at-eol` on the web server

In theory this should work. However, git refuses to do this, seemingly choosing file(s) at random that it believes have local changes.

```
Updating bb48022..7eff182
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        app/models/User.php
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

On the web server, I have performed a few file changes - I've added untracked files, and I have changed permissions. git is configured with `filemode = false`, and I also used `git config --global core.autocrlf true` to enable auto CRLF handling.

`git diff --ignore-space-at-eol` returns no differences. `git status` shows a about a dozen "Changes not staged for commit", but those files haven't really been changed in any way I can notice.

I have tried stashing the erroneous local changes with

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

But it fails just the same at `git pull`

My only working option at this point is to blow away the entire cloned folder and do a fresh clone each time, followed by applying permission changes and doing a `composer install`

I must be missing a fundamental concept here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean they "haven't changed in any way you can notice"?  How *have* they changed?  Whitespace?  Show us your `.gitattributes` file?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. The issue was related to end-of-line management. One dev box is Windows, another is Linux, the git server is Linux, and the web server is Linux.

On the Windows box, I found that `git status` and `git diff` showed the same modified files not staged for commit. My .gitattributes file has `* text=auto` in it, which means that git will try to automatically determine the proper end-of-line to use for all text. For some reason, my Windows box had an index that was not in sync. Following the directions here - http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_end_of_line_conversion - I did the following:

```
$ rm .git/index     # Remove the index to force Git to
$ git reset         # re-scan the working directory
$ git status        # Show files that will be normalized
$ git add -u
$ git add .gitattributes
$ git commit -m "Introduce end-of-line normalization"
```

I performed a fresh clone on the web server and did a few test changes. It seems to be working properly now.